# Remove Access To App Store SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-store

How can we disable/remove/turn off access to the SharePoint App Store for normal users in our organisation but leave it turned on for O365 admins only?

We have gone to the SharePoint Admin Center -> Apps -> Configure Store Settings -> and set both options to No in there.

But the access to the store remains for everyone to see apps.

Answer (score 1):

To specify whether users can get apps from the SharePoint Store, you can follow the steps below.

1. Sign in to Office 365 with your SharePoint Online admin account.
2. Go to the SharePoint admin center.
3. Select Apps on the left, and then select App Catalog.
4. Select Create a new app catalog site, and then select OK.
5. On the Create App Catalog Site Collection page, enter the required 
   information, and then select OK.
6. Back to Apps, and then select Configure Store Settings.
7. Next to App Purchases, select No if you do not want users to be able to get third-party apps.

For more information, you can refer to the following article:

[Configure settings for the SharePoint Store](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-settings-for-the-SharePoint-Store-6b806fb8-9295-441d-b954-07009021dc48)

After this whenever someone tries to add an app will receive this message:

"Sorry, apps are turned off. If you know who runs the server, tell them to enable apps."

If you want to avoid this, you can add JavaScript code in the AddAnApp.aspx page ( add the code under the tag with id="idStorefrontManagementLeftNavBar") to hide this link, this page file is located in folder C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS.

```
<script language="javascript">
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('HideStoreLink');
function HideStoreLink(){
var lis=document.getElementById('idStorefrontManagementLeftNavBar').getElementsByTagName('li');
lis[7].style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
</script>
```

Comment: The store is still turned on in this scenario in your answer so users can still access it.  How can we disable access completely to the store for users?

Comment: I don't think you can disable it for certain people, you can only restrict them to add an app. If that doesn't fill your needs you can hide the link with the JS code I edited my post with.

Comment: Hi @ranbo, Can you kindly explain how can we add the JS snippet for SPO? I don't think we can access C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS on the server.